# Indexes in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, indexing

Could some one tell me why this code does not work, the error is near the keyword WITH

```
create index i_ploc 
on project (Plocation) 
with fillfactor = 60;
```

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'fillfactor=60' at line 1

Comment: What exactly is the error message?

Comment: have you heard of SQL Server books online?

Comment: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'fillfactor= 60' at line 1 SQL Statement: create index i_ploca on project (Plocation) with fillfactor= 60

Comment: @samsam Wait.... you've mentioned sql server in tags - but in your error text it is said about MySQL? So what is your **real** RDBMS?

Comment: **to your MySQL** >> you have tagged for SQL Server. Also, for questions like these, always include the exact error message **in** your question. GL!

Comment: SQL Server workbench

Comment: Retagged - this is **`mysql`** - ***NOT*** (Microsoft) SQL Server !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
  CREATE INDEX i_ploc ON project (Plocation) WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80);
```

Default Syntax :

```
  CREATE INDEX IX_Employee_OrganizationLevel_OrganizationNode ON HumanResources.Employee  
   (OrganizationLevel, OrganizationNode)   
WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80);
```

Comment: still the same error, I am afraid I am using the wrong sheet

Comment: @anurag-systematix  Still having a problem wirh the keyword WITH it is said that it is not valid in this position

Comment: @samsam I think the problem is with "project (Plocation)" in the above line I   think you should use the key or column name with project like project.projectId

Comment: I  have just restarted the computer and it works thankyou :)

Comment: @samsam Please vote up the above solution or comment if that help you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to wrap fillfactor and other parameters after `with` in brackets:

```
create index i_ploc on project (Plocation) with (fillfactor=60);
```

**Update**.

It was incorrect server tagged in question - SQL server instead of MySQL which OP uses (as it became clear from further comments).

So for MySQL anser is:

You **can't** use `fillfactor` in MySQL indexes, it doesn't supports this feature.

See [MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) for details.

Comment: I am using an SQL file in SQLserver workbench, is the right way?

Comment: @samsam As from error text you've posted in comments - you're using MySQL as a server. And MySQL Workbench as tool to run your queries (by the way there is no such a thing as "sql server workbench"). I've updated the answer.